# Jquery ajax add variable with serialize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I use ajax request post and I add another var in data like

```
$.ajax({
 url: action_url,
 type: "POST",
 data: formData + "&par1=1",
 success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
 },
 error: function() {
     alert("Oops..!! Problem Ocurred. Please Try Again..!!");
 }
})
```

then you see +&par1=1

i want to change 1 into variable how could I do it?

Comment: i like to use formData+"&par1=$var,

Comment: You must add data to formData using formData.append("key", "value").

Comment: What is `formData` in this context ?

Comment: using double qoute ?

Comment: formdata serailize form from to send post

Comment: Well then `formData+"&par1=" + yourVariable,`